# How to use MUI Drawer in a separate .jsx file with BrowserRouter?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router, react-router-dom

I have prepared [a simple test case at Github](https://github.com/afarber/react-questions/tree/main/router-nav-drawer) for my question:

[image: screenshot]

In my [App.jsx](https://github.com/afarber/react-questions/blob/main/router-nav-drawer/src/) there is following code:

```
<NavDrawer />

<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="page1" element={<Page1 />} />
    <Route path="page2" element={<Page2 />} />
    <Route path="page3" element={<Page3 />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<Page4 />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

And in the [NavDrawer.jsx](https://github.com/afarber/react-questions/tree/main/router-nav-drawer/src/components) I have the code:

```
const drawerLinks = [
  { text: "Page 1", path: "/page1", icon: <CarCrash /> },
  { text: "Page 2", path: "/page2", icon: <Help /> },
  { text: "Page 3", path: "/page3", icon: <Directions /> },
  { text: "Page 4", path: "/page4", icon: <CarRepair /> },
];

function MyListItem({ text, path, icon }) {
  return (
    <ListItem disablePadding>
      <ListItemButton>
        <ListItemIcon>{icon}</ListItemIcon>
        <Link to={path}>
          <ListItemText primary={text} />
        </Link>
      </ListItemButton>
    </ListItem>
  );
}

export default function NavDrawer() {
  return (
    <Drawer>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <nav>
          <List>
            {drawerLinks.map((item, index) => (
              <MyListItem key={index} icon={item.icon} text={item.text} />
            ))}
          </List>
        </nav>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Drawer>
  );
}
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens when I click one of the `Link`s in the `Drawer`, the displayed page stays the `Page4` and there is no messages or errors printed in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NavDrawer` component is rendering its own `BrowserRouter` component completely separate from the `BrowserRouter` that `App` renders. The links clicked on in `NavDrawer` are handled by `NavDrawer`'s router and the other main router is completely unaware of any navigation actions that were effected and handled.

You need only one router per application, generally at or near the root level of the app.

Remove `BrowserRouter` from `NavDrawer` and nest `NavDrawer` under the root `BrowserRouter` component so the one single router handles all navigation actions.

```
export default function NavDrawer() {
  return (
    <Drawer>
      <nav>
        <List>
          {myLinks.map((item, index) => (
            <MyListItem key={index} icon={item.icon} text={item.text} />
          ))}
        </List>
      </nav>
    </Drawer>
  );
}
```

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <NavDrawer /> // <-- rendered within routing context
  <Routes>
    <Route path="page1" element={<Page1 />} />
    <Route path="page2" element={<Page2 />} />
    <Route path="page3" element={<Page3 />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<Page4 />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've received a friendly answer by [ulvesked at Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/react/comments/1ane4tv/comment/kpwzrge/) -

I have to use not two, but a single `BrowserRouter` at the top App.jsx file.

Also, I missed to pass the `path` argument to the `Link`s in the `Drawer`.

Now the app works as intended:

[image: screenshot]